# SQL: Running Query For All Combinations of Groups

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table ("my_table"):

```
  id year var1 var3 date_1
1  1 2017    1    1    NA
2  1 2018    0    1    NA
3  1 2019    1    1    NA
4  2 2017    0    1    NA
5  2 2018    1    1    NA
6  3 2017    1    1    NA
7  3 2018    1    1    NA
8  3 2019    0    1    NA
```

I have the following query:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        year,
        SUM(var1) AS var1mod,
        date_1
    FROM my_table
    WHERE var3 = 1
    GROUP BY id, year, date1
),

cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM cte1
    WHERE var1mod = 0
),

cte3 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT year) AS year_count
    FROM cte1
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte2)
    AND date_1 IS NULL
    GROUP BY id
),

cte4 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        MIN(year) AS min_year
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT
    year_count,
    COUNT(*) AS count_per_year
FROM cte3
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte4 WHERE min_year = 2000)
GROUP BY year_count;
```

**My Question:**

- In the above query, I am running this for min_year = 2000 and var1mod = 0
- **Is it possible to run this query for all possible combinations of min_year and var1mod?**

Currently, I have manually copy/pasted this query multiple times and used a series of UNION ALL statements to accomplish this task - but can someone please show me how I can aggregate this query to run it for all possible combinations of min_year and var1mod?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is using SQL Server - I do not have an instance of Netezza to test on but there is no specific T-SQL syntax AFAIU. Also note, the sample data did not have `date_1` in it

This only gets you halfway to your goal. There is a lot of nesting of CTE and while this implements the multiple years, also implementing different `var1mod` values might be difficult as I do not know how you would know what values are available. Most likely we would have to refactor and somehow add the different mod values as another grouping factor.

The approach is to add all available years to `cte3` by doing a `CROSS JOIN`. Then we can use `EXISTS` to look at combinations of years and ids to filter. Because of this approach, we added the year to the list of columns selected in the final query.

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        year,
        SUM(var1) AS var1mod
    FROM my_table
    WHERE var3 = 1
    GROUP BY id, year
),

cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM cte1
    WHERE var1mod = 0
),

cte3 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT year) AS year_count
    FROM cte1
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte2)
    GROUP BY id
),

cte4 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        MIN(year) AS min_year
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT
    year_count,
    years.year as min_year,
    COUNT(*) AS count_per_year

FROM cte3
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM cte1) years

WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT null
    FROM cte4
    WHERE cte4.id = cte3.id
     AND cte4.min_year = years.year)

GROUP BY year_count, years.year;
```

Data

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id int,
    year int,
    var1 int,
    var3 int);
INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES(1, 2017, 1, 1),
 (1, 2018, 0, 1),
  (1, 2019, 1, 1),
  (2, 2017, 0, 1),
  (2, 2018, 1, 1),
  (3, 2017, 1, 1),
  (3, 2018, 1, 1),
  (3, 2019, 0, 1),
  (4, 2020, 0, 1);
```